# How can I catch autoplay DOMException?

Tags: javascript, exception, audio, promise

When I try to run Audio.play() before a user has interacted with a page, it throws an error:

> `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`

How can I catch the exception so I am not littering the console log? I would like to try to load an Audio programmatically and clean up the error, but the default JavaScript try/catch does not apply successfully.

Comment: Would a try/catch not work?

Comment: I tried a try/catch block and it didn't work. What I found in searching is that there is a promise involved and it apparently can be caught, but I haven't seen exactly how to implement it.

Comment: It might be promise, if so you can use `.catch()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [this post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/02/firefox-66-to-block-automatically-playing-audible-video-and-audio/):

> In general, the advice for web authors when calling HTMLMediaElement.play(), is to not assume that calls to play() will always succeed, and to always handle the promise returned by play() being rejected.

Because play() returns a promise we can chain a [.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) call to handle the error:

```
Audio.play().catch(error => {
  // Autoplay was blocked. Do something
})
```